# Is it possible to convert the language of contacts according to language of publication?

Tags: outbound-email, audience-manager

Is it possible to get the name of contacts according to publication language from Audience Manager. Like if user entered his/her name in English and if a dutch language publication is going to send newsletter then contacts name should be converted into dutch language. Please guide me.

Comment: How do you "convert" a name into a different language? My name is "Bjørn van Dommelen" regardless of the language used...

Comment: How will it be written in different languages. For example English and Chinese as both languages is uses different characters.

Comment: If someone is Chinese, it's likely that they will have entered their name in Chinese. Attempting to automatically convert that to English or another language will likely end in embarrassment.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything out-of-the-box for that, but you can certainly implement it however you choose. Typically you would have a localized template for the Mailing which will write everything in the language for the Publication -- including the order of fields and potentially the 'localized' version of Contact data if so required.

In general, though, it seems likely that Contacts will enter the data that they want you to use (read: I wouldn't try to 'translate' their names)